# Spivak calculus chapter 19 problem 34.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Spivak's Calculus. 3rd edition. Chapter 19, problem 34. [image]

And in the Answer Book the solution on $b)$ was given:

[image: ![enter image description here]

My question:
Even the question on $b)$ came to me weird. The author says that we have prove that:$$\int_a^b f(x)\phi(x) dx=\phi(a) \int_a^\xi f(x) dx$$ But given formula: $$\int_a^b f(x)\phi(x) dx=\phi(a) \int_a^\xi f(x) dx +\phi(b)\int_\xi^b f(x)$$ Meanwhile the result is true when $\phi(b)=0$ We immediately get $$\int_a^b f(x)\phi(x) dx=\phi(a) \int_a^\xi f(x) dx$$Why we need so complex solution???

I am not native english speaker maybe I cant understand clearly the text.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the question which is weird for you?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos as I said it is obvious. Meanwhile $\phi(b)=0$ why we just dont put it in formula. Instead of doing complex combination.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information which can be conveyed in text.  For details, please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/ .

Comment: Could you try to explain in your own words what you think the question is about (I'm assuming it's question $b$ you are focused on here) and/or the proposed solution so we can try to see where your problem is?

Comment: Yes @BrunoB I have edited. Exactly the question in b) looks for me uncertain.

Comment: @BrunoB I have edited the question please.look at again. Maybe I could explain my problem

Comment: I have often argued, to anyone who is willing to listen, that words like "obvious", "clear", and "trivial" are bad mathematical exposition.  Usually, when a person says that something is "obvious" in mathematics, one of three things is true:  (1) they have never worked out the details of a proof, and just assume that it is true, (2) they don't actually know how the proof goes, or (3) they are basically saying that anyone who doesn't immediately see the proof is too dumb to bother explaining it to. And this is assuming that the "obvious" statement is actually true (which isn't always the case).

Comment: Perhaps you could explain to us why the result which you claim is obvious is, in fact, obvious?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sir, this problem took my time and attention a lot. I dont need another phylosophical statements. I cant understand simlpy one thing: author says that the result holds when $\phi(b)=0$ Meanhwhile the result holds on this case what we have to prove?. Because just consider $\phi(b)=0$ on the formula.

Comment: “The author says that we have prove that: “ formula you type is still incorrect

Comment: And dear downvoters nobody oblige you ta answer or pay pay attention. I am intetested in math seriosly and want to learn and understand something on math. Please dont interfere

Comment: Thank you @Tim corrected

Comment: @emilagazade I think they are teaching you the spirit of learning math, which is useful and better than you do many exercises in this way. I suggest you write your own proof and whole attempts here.

Comment: @emilagazade A number of people here have indicated that they don't understand what your question is.  You have repeatedly asserted that some part of the argument is "obvious", but you have not actually written down any of your own thoughts or arguments, and this particular thing which you assert as "obvious" is, it would appear, *not* obvious to many of us.  **Explain it.**  Moreover, as I indicated above, you *should not* use images to convey text.  I provided you with a [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/) to a post which has links which might help you write your math.

Comment: @XanderHenderson. Given formula: $$\int_a^b f(x)\phi(x) dx=\phi(a)\int_a^\xi f(x) dx+\phi(b)\int_\xi^b f(x) dx$$  meanwhile $\phi(b)=0$ then we have $$\int_a^b f(x)\phi(x) dx=\phi(a)\int_a^\xi f(x)$$ still uncertain??

Comment: Is the result true for functions which satisfy $\phi(b) = 0$?  I don't see a proof of that anywhere...

Comment: @XanderHenderson look at the text on picture author says:  Prove that if the result is true for nonincreasing $\phi$ satisfying $\phi(b)= 0$ then it is true for all nonincreasing $\phi$

Comment: @emilagazade note you need to prove for all function.

Comment: @emilagazade Yes, the author is telling **you**, the reader, to prove that statement.  It is written in the imperative.  The author has not given that proof.

Comment: @XanderHenderson thank you for petient. It is due to my "bad" english. I understood. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @emilagazade I found that there are two parts that also make me confused and deleted my comments, it is not quite your problem of bad English. First, you apply the formula to prove for all function part. Second, this reduces the theorem into solving the statements after word “Thus”. This means you still need to prove the statement and it is the same as you prove the theorem.

Comment: @Tim thank you I am still thinking. I apreciate your help very much.

Comment: The proof of theorem is not complete. To complete the whole proof, the whole paragraph after “thus” is just your exercise (c), but you can’t apply the formula which you think obvious.

Comment: @Tim thank you again. At least I got it. First I thought that we already accepted the theorem now are proving it's special cases. But the problem was differnent. We are reducing theorem into more easy case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been broken into steps to try and help clarify what the essential ingredients in proving the result are, but you don't have to follow them if they don't seem intuitive. The result you want to prove is that, for any function $\phi$ which is non-increasing or non-decreasing on $[a,b]$, given any continuous function $f$, there is a $\xi \in (a,b)$ (depending on $f$) such that
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
\int_a^b f(t)\phi(t)\mathrm{d}t = \phi(a).\int_a^{\xi} f(t)\phi(t)\mathrm{d}t + \phi(b).\int_{\xi}^b f(t)\phi(t)\mathrm{d}t
$$

Part a) claims that knowing the result for nondecreasing $\phi$ implies the result for nonincreasing $\phi$, but it is also fine to try to prove it for one or the other, to begin with.

Similarly, the assumption that $\phi(b)=0$ makes some calculations easier, and therefore Spivak asks you to think about why the result for $\phi$ satisfying $\phi(b)=0$ implies the result for any nondecreasing $\phi$.

Thus parts (a) and (b) aim to reduce the general result to the special case where $\phi$ is nonincreasing and $\phi(b)=0$, and the condition that $\phi(b)=0$ means that the expression on the right-hand side of our desired identity becomes
$$
\phi(a).\int_{a}^{\xi} f(t)\phi(t)\mathrm{d}t.
$$
I think part of your confusion was the direction of the implication Spivak wants you to show -- if you know the existence of $\xi$ for any $\phi$ then it certainly gives you a suitable $\xi$ for a $\phi$ satisfying $\phi(b)=0$, but what you are asked to do is to show that, if you can prove there is a $\xi$ for which $\int_a^b f(t)\phi(t)\mathrm{d}t = \phi(a)\int_{a}^{\xi}f(t)\phi(t)\mathrm{d}t$ if $\phi$ is nonincreasing and $\phi(b)=0$, can you deduce the existence of $\xi$ satisfying $(\dagger)$ for an arbitrary nonincreasing $\phi$?

To give a hint for how to show part (b), for example, consider separately what happens to the lefthand side and right-hand side of $(\dagger)$ when you replace $\phi(t)$ with $\phi(t)+C$ for any $C\in \mathbb R$.